# How to put a variable in anchor tag <a href="somelink"+{!variable} >

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to make a share on linkedin link on my lightning component
of community like this :

```
 <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=my_url_here;&amp;title="+{!v.SingleBlog.Title__c}+"&amp;summary=sdfsjf"   target="_new" >  Linkedin      </a>
```

But When I am saving this its giving me an error :

Getting

```
Field Integrity Exception : 
Failed to save undefined: markup://c:BlogDetail:70,162: ParseError at [row,col]:[71,162] Message: Element type "a" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".:
```

I know its because of the variable {!v.SingleBlog.Title__c} whose value I want to append in share url at runtime.

***How to put this variable's value in url?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't say if you need to or not but if you do

```
{!variable + 'sometext'}
```

So if I was adding a dynamic class

```
Class="{!variable + 'slds-button slds-button-brand'}"
```

As for your url try

```
a href="{!'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + URLENCODE(my_url_here) + '&title=' + v.SingleBlog.Title__c + '&summary=sdfsjf'}"   target="_new" >  Linkedin      </a>
```

In its simplest form this will output `https://waiting` (waiting is the value of `boxStatus`) for the url when Click Me is clicked

```
<a href="{!'https://' + v.boxStatus}">Click me</a>
```

Comment: `<a href="{!'https://' + v.boxStatus}">Click me</a>`  - this one worked.
Thanks @Eric

Answer (score 1):

**Visualforce**

You don't need to join the static string and the dynamic variable strings with +

you can directly use the expression variable within the same string like below

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=my_url_here;&amp;title={!v.SingleBlog.Title__c}&amp;summary=sdfsjf"   target="_new" >  Linkedin      </a>
```

**Lightning**

```
<a href="{! 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=my_url_here;&amp;title=' + v.SingleBlog.Title__c + '&amp;summary=sdfsjf' }"   target="_new" >  Linkedin      </a>
```

Comment: I tried and its giving me another error: 

`Failed to save undefined: Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}: Source `

Comment: totally missed you are doing this in lightning.. updated my answer for both lightning and visualforce..